# How do I run an external NFC reader in Flutter Windows

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web, flutter-windows

How do I run an external NFC reader in Flutter Windows

I tried to find a NFC package that supports Windows, but I couldn't find any solutions
.

I bought an NFC reader and I want to use it in Flutter Windows.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hello... Have you found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried.

If NFC reader connects a computer with a USB port.

You can try [serial_port_win32](https://pub.dev/packages/serial_port_win32) to
receive data from COM port.